# General Looping question

Tags: javascript

```
var answer = " ";
var correct = "4";
var question = "What is 2 * 2?";

for(i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
    answer = prompt(question, "0");
    if (answer == correct) {
        alert("Your answer is correct!");
        break;
    }
}
```

How many chances would the user have before the break command got executed?

Comment: The user will have unlimited chances. They can refresh the page over and over and over until they get it right.

Comment: @Mark: yes it's valid Javascript code.  Maybe valid in some other language too though.

Comment: @Brian, I know it's valid JS, I was asking the OP so I could update the tags appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user would have 3 chances unless they guessed right on the 1st or 2nd chance.  Then they would only have 1 or 2 chances respectively.

i = 2 in the first iteration, i = 3 in the next iteration and i = 4 in the last iteration.  Before another iteration starts i is set to 5 and the condition fails.

Answer (score 2):

The user will have 3 chances (i=2, i=3 and i=4).

Comment: Correct; "for(i = 2; i < 5; i++)" will execute for i = 2, 3 and 4